# What tax/social security would I have to pay any UK salary I earn while a US resident?

Tags: usa, taxes, uk-citizens

I'm really confused about this. I read a lot about US residents living abroad and earning. I am not a US Citizen but I am/will be a resident soon.

If I owned a company in the UK and got paid a salary from the UK, what taxes would be incurred in the USA. I understand I would have to pay the normal due NI and income tax in the UK. But what US taxes would be due? Would I have to pay the Self Employment tax for foreign income? Or would it just be some income tax? And would state, city and school district tax me on my foreign income?

Answer (score 1):

> But what US taxes would be due?

US taxes its residents on worldwide income. So regular taxes will be due.

> Would I have to pay the Self Employment tax for foreign income?

If it is self employment - yes.

> Or would it just be some income tax? And would state, city and school
>   district tax me on my foreign income?

Yes.

Keep in mind horrendous amount of reporting you'll need to do in the US if you have foreign bank accounts, foreign companies, foreign pensions, foreign investments, etc etc. Better talk to a licensed tax adviser (EA/CPA) who's familiar with all that and the relevant tax treaties.